# Compile text using command line compiler, not a file

Tags: command-line, compilation, lua

I'm using `luac -p file.lua` to parse files to check for syntax errors. Is it possible to do something like this:

```
luac -p | [a bunch of text]
```

Someone mentioned something about 'piping' but I couldn't figure out how that would help.

What I'm wanting to do is take text from a program I am writing and put all that text into the compiler with `-p` so it just parses the text. Basically I want to check syntax of my program's textarea without having to write it to a file first.

Comment: Are you using Windows command line for this? If so you can loop it like so `for %a in ("C:\Folder\*.lua") do luac -p | "%~a"`....

Comment: c:\folder\*.lua seems to refer to a file. I'm trying to compile text without a file - maybe from the clipboard or just adding all the text into the command prompt. I'm doing this from java Process execution. (also a side note, I'm hoping to get this working with mac and windows)

Comment: Yes, `luac` accepts program from stdin: `luac -p -`  So, just run `cat program.lua | luac -p -`

Comment: Not sure how that works... what is program.lua? remember, I have no file, it's text going into the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

In bash you can do

```
luac -p - << EOF
```

Then type your text. To indicate end, just type

```
EOF
```

on new line and press enter.

Comment: I tried `luac -p - << print("Hello) \n EOF` and it just starts luac or something and doesn't return the error which is the missing " in that text.